# Wordpress why i'm Not getting folder name on site url after site migration

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, broken-links, wordpress-admin

I have migrated our WordPress website from the live to the local environment by using the updraft plus plugin.

After migration, I have edited the home & siteurl to **http://localhost/sitename** instead of the domain URL in the `wp_options` table.
Also, I have re-saved the changes in the General and Permalink setting under `wp-admin`.

The `wp-admin` works properly and also the site working properly, but I am facing the issue of a broken link.

All the URLs which are started with "/wp-content/themes/....." are not able to take the whole localhost site URL (i.e. localhost/sitename), It is taken as "localhost/wp-content/themes/...." only.

This means the site name is missing on each and every URL, that's why I am not able to load styles and bootstrap links that are on the website.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example of using a wordpress function called `site_url()` instead of using `localhost/sitename` when you develop your app!

You could read more about it on the documentation page:

> [WordPress `site_url()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/)

The main benefit of using this function is, you will have to update your `production url` just once, in one place which is the admin menu and it'll get updated every where throughout your site where you've called `site_url()` on your links.